# How to increment fraction/denominator in loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to develop a Python 3 program that will allow the user to choose a denominator and evaluate an equation. For Example:

- The user selects 5 to be the denominator
- The equation will increment until the given denominator
- (1/1) + (1/2) + (1/3) + (1/4) + (1/5)
- The output should be (2.283333)

My code:

```
d = input ("Select a denominator") 
for i in range(d)
    d += (1/d)
    print(d)
```

So far I'm only able to ask the user for the input/denominator. I tried putting it in a loop but I am doing something wrong. This is what prints out:

```
5.2
5.392307
5.577757
5.757040
5.930740
```

Comment: cannot divide by `0`

Comment: I think you need to use more than one variable.

Comment: `range(d)` goes from `0` to `d`. `1/0` is undefined.

Comment: You are not using `i`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: change first line in loop to `d += 1/i` and the range to `range(1,d+1)`

Comment: Your meta-problem is lack of debugging.  Insert a simple, tracing `print` at the top of your loop, such as `print(i, d)` and look at the values.  Do they match what you did when you worked through the problem by hand?  Your code has several problems; test one line -- or even one expression -- at a time.  Don't add more until the first part works.

Comment: @Jab Who's dividing by 0?

Comment: if OP used `i` as denominator then range would be 0-d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

```
final_denominator = int(input("Select a denominator: "))
total = 0
for i in range(1, final_denominator + 1):
    total += 1 / i
print(total)
```

- You need to convert the inputted string to an integer with `int()`
- Use a different variable for the total and the final denominator.
- `range(x)` goes from 0 to `x - 1`, to go from 1 to x you need `range(1, x + 1)`.
- You need to add `1 / i` rather than `1 / final_denominator` to the total.

Alternatively, this is a good use for a generator expression:

```
final_denominator = int(input("Select a denominator: "))
total = sum(1 / i for i in range(1, final_denominator + 1))
print(total)
```

Comment: I forgot to add `int()`, already fixed it.